# Trying to edit the breadcrumbs for views using Custom Breadcrumbs module

Tags: 7, views, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to use the custom breadcrumbs module with Drupal 7, and I'm having issues generating a custom breadcrumb - it only seems to want to let me edit nodes/add custom bread crumbs to nodes.

How would I go about adding a custom breadcrumb to a view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The stable Drupal 7 version of Custom Breadcrumbs is currently in the 1.x branch; support for Views has only been added in the 2.x branch, for which there is no stable release for either version (there's an RC available for Drupal 6 but only a dev version for Drupal 7).

I think your options are:

1. Try the 7.x-2.x-dev branch and report any problems you find back to the module issue queue
2. Implement `hook_preprocess_views_view()` for your view and set the breadcrumb in there programatically (with code similar to the below).
3. Add custom PHP code to the header of your view (not advised):

   ```
   $breadcrumb[] = l('Home','<front>');
   $breadcrumb[] = l('View Name', 'path/to/view');
   drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
   ```
4. A number of other 'hacky' methods that involve overriding the `theme_breadcrumb` function and making changes based on the path of a View (see [this post](http://drupal.org/node/156038) for some examples).

Comment: Do you have a recommended method (or possibly a different module)? I'd prefer to not add custom PHP code to each header - that seems tedious and obviously it would increase the difficulty of maintenance. I'm not quite sure how to do 2. 1 certainly seems the easiest, but there might be bug issues.

Comment: Personally I'd go with option 2, it can be done at either the theme or module level and is definitely a 'Drupal' way to do it. Plus you're not exposed to potential bugs or giving yourself a maintenance headache like you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

This is a functional example of #2 which is hooked to view 7.x-3.x that has contextual filters on two displays based on term ID (base-path/%). The base-path is not valid, so this masks it out to just "Home > TERM NAME"

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_execute().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'products') {
    switch ($view->current_display) {
      case 'by_occasion':
      case 'by_type':
        $breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
        if (!empty($view->args)) {
          if ($term = taxonomy_term_load(current($view->args))) {
            $breadcrumb[] = check_plain($term->name);
          }
        }
        drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with hook_page_alter, checking current page url against views page url.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_alter().
 */
function mymodule_page_alter(&$page) {
  /* ----- set breadcrumb for some view pages ----*/

  if (request_path() == 'announcement') {
    $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Home'), NULL);
    $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Announcement'), 'announcement');
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
  } 
  ...
}
```